# Unpacking a backdoor program for studying

Tags: malware, unpacking

I wanted to learn something about unpacking malware manuelly and found the following link:

```
  writequit.org/blog/?p=165.
```

As you can see, the malware in that example begins with the PUSHAD instruction. (I thought it would be a good link because 2 days ago I started to analyze a malware which begins with the same PUSHAD instruction. It was also packed with UPX like the malware in that example of the given link)

So, I downloaded the malware of the example for testing purpose.

What I did:

When I step into PUSHAD instruction(pressing F7), double-clicking ESP in combination with "Following in Dump", then I choose the first 4 bytes of the first row (ESP address) in the hex window. Then I go to Breakpoint -> Hardware, on access -> Dword. Then F9. 
(I hope I could explain it right but you can be sure that I did exactly the same things as in the example of the link)

My problem:

The first thing:

After I click ESP -> "Follow in Dump" , the 4 bytes of the first row looks like this: 00 00 00 00.
(So, only zeros. Not the same like in the example which was 08 02 91 7c as you can see)

The second thing:

When I choose the 00 00 00 00 -> Breakpoint -> Hardware, on access -> Dword, then I let it run (F9) but the malware does not run to a location where I can find POPAD or JMP .... as in the example. 
In my case, after all that it runs to a location (especially, running ends in a LEAVE instruction) with the following:

```
   ...
   ...
   LEA EAX, DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-3C]
   PUSH EAX
   CALL DWORD PTR DS: [<&ntdll.RtlRaiseException>]
   LEAVE                                             <----- here, it ends
   RETN 10
   MOV DWORD PTR SS: [EBP-40], EAX
   ...
   ...
```

So, even if I scroll hundreds of lines upwards or downwards, I could not find a POPAD instruction.

My question:

Why it is so? Do I need to configure something in the ollydbg settings ?

I hope someone can help me in that case, because although I do the same steps as in the example, I have different results.

best regards,

Comment: 0. What OS do you have on research machine? 1. Restart the Olly session and you should break on 0x424231. 2. Note the EDI register, before execution `pushed`. 3. Do you see, that EDI has 7c910208? 4. In addition, scroll down from 0x424231 and you should find `popad` at 0x424386.

Answer (score 6):

Your mistake is that you put the breakpoint while being on the `PUSHAD` instruction (meaning it wasn't executed yet).

---

I just unpacked the file, and this is how you do it:

## 1. Drop the file in Olly and find the `PUSHAD` instruction

Simply do what you did before, and end up here:

[image: Step 1]

## 2. Step once to skip the `PUSHAD`

Now, you got everything pushed, and the decompression can start.

[image: Step 2]

## 3. Put a breapoint on the stack

Now, you've arrived to the point where the stack looks like:

```
## original ESP
## some register's value
## some register's value
## some register's value
## ...
## you are here
```

Now, on the `you are here` point, the decompressor uses the stack, and it grows downwards (to lower addresses).
When it is done using it, it clears the stack, and reaches again your `original ESP` point, where the `popad` instruction writes, and which is what causes the breakpoint to hit.

## 4. Run

Pretty much self-explanatory.
You'll end up here after running:

[image: Step 3]

## 5. Step again

Done, you found the OEP!

[image: OEP]

Now you can dump. I used [OllyDumpEx](http://low-priority.appspot.com/ollydumpex/#download):
[image: OllyDumpEx]

Simply click <kbd>Get EIP as OEP</kbd> while being on the `PUSH EBP` instruction, and then dump: (also write down the EIP<sup>1</sup>)
[image: dump]
[image: fix OEP]

## 6. Fix IAT

Now, you want to fix the IAT to properly see the used APIs!
Do not close Olly and don't step, just dump and leave it as is.

Open `ImportREC`, pick the process, and press <kbd>IAT AutoSearch</kbd>, then <kbd>Get Imports</kbd>.

[image: IAT fixing]

Sometimes it may not find the OEP automatically, so just take the OEP you found before<sup>1</sup>, put it there, and click <kbd>IAT AutoSearch</kbd> and then <kbd>Get Imports</kbd> again, and then dump.

## 7. Taking a look at the file in IDA

Now you can analyze the file.

This is how it looks like when manually unpacked:

[image: dumped]

And this is how the UPX unpacked (`upx -d`) version looks like:

[image: upx unpacked]

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, UPX was used and it can be unpacked by UPX itself [see this example](http://m0rphiz3.tk/?p=12).
To address scrolling to find the entry point, its because you are in a different module loaded by the binary. You're probably getting into ntdll.dll module disassembly.

Comment: the question clearly stated that the user wanted to unpack manually so the tool for unpacking is not really relevant.